# How to use a custom UIViewController with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms-App which runs without any problems on iOS prior to iOS 11. My app has a custom menu with some menu items on the bottom of the screen. Since iOS 11.x it behaves differently on screen edges which means that there is a heavy noticeable delay when the user touches the screen edges. I know I have to override `PreferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` in the `UIViewController` class but how to tell Xamarin to use my `CustomUIViewController` (where I am overriding `PreferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures`) over the normal `UIViewController`?

I already tried with a custom renderer for my main page (which is a `ContentPage`) but Xamarin creates its own `RootViewController`. The `UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController` is created by Xamarin and I have no control over that.

So my question is: How can I tell Xamarin (using Xamarin.Forms) to use my `CustomUIViewController` (where I am overriding `PreferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures`) as `RootViewController`?

P.S. I cannot create my own `UIWindow` in the `FinishedLaunching` method of the `AppDelegate` class to assign my own `RootViewController` because I am using Xamarin.Forms -> Would lead to "Foundation.ModelNotImplementedException".

Comment: I can reproduce it, this may be an issue. I can achieve this on Xamarin.iOS, but with a renderer it fails. I have reported an issue here:[https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2241](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2241).

Comment: Thanks for that hint. Only to make sure it really is an issue...Did you call "SetNeedsUpdateOfScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures()" in your renderer where you are overriding "PreferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures"? In fact you did not, I did and still no change! The getter of "PreferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures" never gets called!

Comment: No, I didn't call that event. But I do the same thing on Xamarin.iOS in a ViewController. `PreferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` will be called. So I think this may be an issue and `SetNeedsUpdateOfScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures()` is not the problem.